# grep -P no longer works. How can I rewrite my searches?

Tags: macos, perl, shell

It looks like the new version of OS X no longer supports `grep -P` and as such has made some of my scripts stop working, for example:

```
var1=`grep -o -P '(?<=<st:italic>).*(?=</italic>)' file.txt`
```

I need to capture grep's result to a variable and I need to use zero-width assertions, as well as `\K`:

```
var2=`grep -P -o '(property:)\K.*\d+(?=end)' file.txt`
```

Any alternatives would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how about installing gnu grep?

Comment: Are you sure it's the `-P`? Mine has it.

Comment: @Kevin It was removed in 10.8.

Comment: @LauriRanta I have 10.8... Interestingly, it's still in the usage but actually using it doesn't work

Comment: Cannot install anything on these machines unfortunately.

Comment: @Kent care to elaborate on how one might do that?

Comment: [It really seems to have been removed](http://www.dirtdon.com/?p=1452), what a dick move of Apple if this happened intentionally.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth OS X's `grep` actually changed from `grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1` in 10.7 to `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD` in 10.8. I guess it was because of GPL. The FreeBSD `grep` is also based on GNU `grep` and both versions of `grep` are from 2002. `--label` and `-u` / `--unix-byte-offets` were also removed in 10.8. `-z` / `--decompress`, `-J` / `--bz2decompress`, `--exclude-dir`, `--include-dir`, `-S`, `-O`, and `-p` were added in 10.8. `-Z` changed from `--null` to `--decompress`.

Comment: @LauriRanta Thanks for the info, that explains it...much appreciated. I don't have an OS X/*BSD installation handy but read that `BSD grep` is way slower than `GNU grep`, can you confirm if this is still the case on 10.8 (compared to `GNU grep` installed via homebrew, for example)? I'm just curious.

Comment: The FreeBSD `grep` that comes with OS X is from 2002, and https://wiki.freebsd.org/BSDgrep still says that "the only TODO item is improving performance", so yeah. `time grep aa /usr/share/dict/words>/dev/null` takes about 0.09 seconds with OS X's grep and about 0.01 seconds with a new GNU grep on repeated runs on my iMac.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

If you want to do the minimal amount of work, change

```
grep -P 'PATTERN' file.txt
```

to

```
perl -nle'print if m{PATTERN}' file.txt
```

and change

```
grep -o -P 'PATTERN' file.txt
```

to

```
perl -nle'print $& while m{PATTERN}g' file.txt
```

So you get:

```
var1=`perl -nle'print $& while m{(?<=<st:italic>).*(?=</italic>)}g' file.txt`
var2=`perl -nle'print $& while m{(property:)\K.*\d+(?=end)}g' file.txt`
```

---

In your specific case, you can achieve simpler code with extra work.

```
var1=`perl -nle'print for m{<st:italic>(.*)</italic>}g' file.txt`
var2=`perl -nle'print for /property:(.*\d+)end/g' file.txt`
```

Comment: This works great but it returns all matches as where the grep I used only returned the first match. any idea about how to return just the first match?

Comment: @ironintention: add `| tail -1` to the end of the pipeline.

Comment: `grep` always returns all matching lines (unless you use one of the options where it prints none at all). Anyway, `if (/.../) { print $1; last; }` will cause it to only print the first match.

Comment: I used this to get out the urls of a sitemap - thanks mate, would not have made it without your post! perl -nle'print $1 if m{<loc>(.*)</loc>}' sitemap.xml

Comment: @Christian, Would only take 3 lines to do it with a proper XML parser such as XML::LibXML. (Key line: `say $_->textContent for $doc->findnodes('//loc');`)

Comment: @Ikegami I needed this only one time for a specific use case. The result be trashed in the way. I am happy with it right now. Anyway thanks for letting me know about libxml. There are times i regret my lack of perl-fu.

Comment: Adjusted to handle multiple matches per line like `grep -o`

Answer (score 150):

If your scripts are for your use only, you can install `grep` from [`homebrew-core`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core) using [`brew`](http://brew.sh/):

```
brew install grep
```

Then it's available as `ggrep` (GNU `grep`).
it doesn't replaces the system `grep` (you need to put the installed grep before the system one on the `PATH`).

The version installed by `brew` includes the `-P` option, so you don't need to change your scripts.

If you need to use these commands with their normal names, you
can add a "gnubin" directory to your PATH from your bashrc like:

```
PATH="/usr/local/opt/grep/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

You can export this line on your ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc to keep it for new sessions.

Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6368697/patrick-mevzek) for a discussion of the pro-s and cons of the old `--with-default-names` option and it's (recent) removal.

Comment: @pepper what didn't work? Likely the path isn't set properly - what's the output of `which grep`? Should be `/usr/local/bin/grep`. It;s a bit mean to downvote before you've checked carefully that there is a problem!

Comment: indeed that is it! But it did not put the installed grep before the system one on the PATH as you said. I'm happy to upvote, I really do not understand the fuss about the point system on this website (can't you just hack around that?). Glad you pointed this out though, I'm setting up an alias for grep ASAP!

Comment: probably better to add `/usr/local/bin` to the front of your PATH. Brew is supposed to set that up I believe? Did you use `--default-names`? Anyway, glad it works (: Not sure about hacking around it, but I think the point system is one of the reasons this site is such a good resource.

Comment: yes I did use --default-names and brew. Not sure if putting /usr/local/bin in the front of your path is better than an alias, just an alternative

Comment: great answer, the only way that makes work. would be great if you can add how to setup an alias to your answer.

Comment: an alternative to `--with-default-names` is to add `alias grep='ggrep'` to your bash profile and let brew dupes keep their prefix

Comment: `--with-default-names` is removed from brew. I had to `brew install grep` to get ggrep and then do as @rymo says and do `alias grep='ggrep'` .

Comment: maybe if your script runs sub-shell an alias would not work. Need to `brew install grep` and then add to your path, or `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/grep/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"`

Answer (score 13):

Install [ack](http://search.cpan.org/dist/ack/) and use it instead. Ack is a grep replacement written in Perl. It has full support for Perl regular expressions.

Comment: I'd like to check this out but this is for work computers so we cannot install anything

Comment: @ironintention: If you can install Perl modules, you're good. Even if you can't add to the local Perl installation you can always use local::lib.

Comment: `ack` is designed to be self-contained; you don't need to actually install it. If you can save a file, mark it as exectutable, and update your `PATH` if necessary, you are good to go.

Comment: Can you please the ack syntax that replaces the above

Comment: @FullDecent: It's almost identical: `ack -o '(property:)\K.*\d+(?=end)' file.txt` (`-o` means the same thing, but you don't need the `-P` with ack)

Answer (score 11):

OS X tends to provide BSD rather than GNU tools. It **does** come with `egrep` however, which is probably all you need to perform regex searches.

example: `egrep 'fo+b?r' foobarbaz.txt`

A snippet from the OSX grep man page:

`grep is used for simple patterns and basic regular expressions (BREs); egrep can handle extended regular expressions (EREs).`

Comment: Direct invocation as egrep is deprecated. The same ability is also available as grep -E. It's... a sad shadow of Perl, lacking lookaround assertions, most of the backslash escapes, options, conditionals, etc :( Power users will hate it, but it does at least do the job.

Comment: Thanks. `grep -E` instead of `grep -P` was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 8):

`use perl;`

```
perl -ne 'print if /regex/' files ...
```

If you need more `grep` options (I see you would like `-o` at least) there are various `pgrep` implementations floating around the net, many of them in Perl.

If "almost Perl" is good enough, PCRE ships with `pcregrep`.

Answer (score 7):

There is another alternative: `pcregrep`.

[Pcregrep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?pcregrep) is a grep with Perl-compatible regular expressions.  It has the exactly same usage as `grep -P`. So it will be compatible with your scripts.

It can be installed with homebrew:

`brew install pcre`

Comment: `Error: No available formula for pcregrep`

Comment: GaborMarton, I edited your answer to include @Martin 's correcting comment, and had to move the formatting around a bit to get over the minimum changes.

Comment: To search through text files that are larger than 20.4 KB, for the equivalent of `grep -o -P 'PATTERN' file.txt`, you must use `pcregrep -o --buffer-size=100K 'PATTERN' file.txt`. Note that there is no `-P` option for `pcregrep`. Note: `pcregrep` is also available for Linux: https://command-not-found.com/pcregrep

Answer (score 4):

How about using the '-E' option? It works fine for me, 
for example, if I want to check for a `php_zip`, `php_xml`, `php_gd2` extension from **php -m** I use:

```
php -m | grep -E '(zip|xml|gd2)'
```

Comment: this works.  Mac uses FreeBSD grep and Linux uses GNU grep...so this fix worked on my macOS sierra

Answer (score 3):

Equivalent of the accepted answer, but without the requirement of the -P switch, which was not present on both machines I had available.

```
find . -type f -exec perl -nle 'print $& if m{\r\n}' {} ';' -exec perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/g' {} '+'
```

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me:

```
    awk  -F":" '/PATTERN/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Perl solution for -P

```
var1=$( perl -ne 'print $1 if m#<st:italic>([^<]+)</st:italic># ' file.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

use the perl one-liner regex by passing the find output with a pipe.
I used **lookbehind** (get **src** links in html) and **lookahead** for **"**  and passed the output of curl (html) to it.

```
bash-3.2# curl stackoverflow.com | perl -0777 -ne '$a=1;while(m/(?<=src\=\")(.*)(?=\")/g){print "Match #".$a." "."$&\n";$a+=1;}'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  239k  100  239k    0     0  1911k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 1919k
Match #1 //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
Match #2 //cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=fb6157e02696
Match #3 https://ssum-sec.casalemedia.com/usermatch?s=183712&amp;cb=https%3A%2F%2Fengine.adzerk.net%2Fudb%2F22%2Fsync%2Fi.gif%3FpartnerId%3D1%26userId%3D
Match #4 //i.stack.imgur.com/817gJ.png" height="16" width="18" alt="" class="sponsor-tag-img">elasticsearch</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-2.0" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;elasticsearch-2.0&#39;" rel="tag">elasticsearch-2.0</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-dsl" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;elasticsearch-dsl&#39;" rel="tag
Match #5 //i.stack.imgur.com/817gJ.png" height="16" width="18" alt="" class="sponsor-tag-img">elasticsearch</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/sharding" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;sharding&#39;" rel="tag">sharding</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/master" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;master&#39;" rel="tag
Match #6 //i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png" height="16" width="18" alt="" class="sponsor-tag-img">android</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/linux" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;linux&#39;" rel="tag">linux</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/camera" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;camera&#39;" rel="tag
Match #7 //i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png" height="16" width="18" alt="" class="sponsor-tag-img">android</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/firebase" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;firebase&#39;" rel="tag"><img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/5d55j.png" height="16" width="18" alt="" class="sponsor-tag-img">firebase</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/firebase-authentication" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;firebase-authentication&#39;" rel="tag
Match #8 //i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png" height="16" width="18" alt="" class="sponsor-tag-img">android</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/ios" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;ios&#39;" rel="tag">ios</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/in-app-purchase" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;in-app-purchase&#39;" rel="tag">in-app-purchase</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/piracy-protection" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;piracy-protection&#39;" rel="tag
Match #9 //i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png" height="16" width="18" alt="" class="sponsor-tag-img">android</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/unity3d" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;unity3d&#39;" rel="tag">unity3d</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/vr" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;vr&#39;" rel="tag
Match #10 http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc.gif" alt="" class="dno
bash-3.2# date
Mon Oct 24 20:57:11 EDT 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with grep suddenly on a docker rebuilt, I found the solution here : https://github.com/firehol/firehol/issues/325

just replaced -oP with -oE

`echo $some_var | grep -oE '\b[0-9a-f]{5,40}\b' | head -1`

Answer (score -1):

Some more options, these also set correct exit status:

- equivalent to `grep -P PATTERN FILE` :

  `perl -e'while(<>){if( (m!PATTERN!) ){$ok++;print}};if(!($ok)){exit 1}' FILE`
- equivalent to `grep -P -i PATTERN FILE` :

  `perl -e'while(<>){if( (m!PATTERN!i) ){$ok++;print}};if(!($ok)){exit 1}' FILE`
- equivalent to `grep -v -P PATTERN FILE` :

  `perl -e'while(<>){if( !(m!PATTERN!) ){$ok++;print}};if(!($ok)){exit 1}' FILE`

For a more cleaner solution use this gist - implemented switches are: -A , -B , -v , -P , -i : https://gist.github.com/torson/bd6931bda0035c4884b2a8c4c64a33b2

Comment: Probably lose the [useless uses of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)