# How to split a file containing non-ascii characters into words, in bash?

Tags: bash, split, non-ascii-characters

For example, I have a file with normal text, like:

```
"Word1 Kuͦn, buͤtten; word4:"
```

I want to get a file with 1 word per line, keeping the punctiuation, and ordered:

```
,
:
;
Word1
Kuͦn
buͤtten
word4
```

The code I use:

```
grep -Eo '\w+|[^\w ]' input.txt | sort -f >> output.txt
```

This the code works almost perfectly, except for one thing: it splits diacretical characters apart from the letters they belong to, as if they were separate words:

```
    ,
    :
    ;
    Word1
    Ku
    ͦ      
    n
    bu 
    ͤ   
    tten
    word4
```

The letters uͦ, uͤ and other with the same diacretics are not in the ASCII table. How can I split my file correctly without deleting or replacing these characters?

Edit:

`locale` output:

```
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Can you please update your question including the output of `locale`?

Comment: The question is updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, U+366 (COMBINING LATIN SMALL LETTER O) is not an alphabetic character. It is a non-spacing mark, unicode category `Mn`, which generally maps to the Posix ctype `cntrl`.

Roughly speaking, an alphabetic grapheme is an alphabetic character possibly followed by one or more combining characters. It's possible to write that as a regex pattern if you have a regex library which implements Unicode general categories. Gnu `grep` is usually compiled with an interface to the popular `pcre` (Perl-compatible regular expression) library, which has reasonably good Unicode support. So if you have Gnu grep, you're in luck.

To enable "perl-like" regular expressions, you need to invoke `grep` with the `-P` option (or as `pgrep`). However, that is not quite enough because by default `grep` will use an 8-bit encoding even if the locale specifies a UTF-8 encoding. So you need to put the regex system into "UTF-8" mode in order to get it to recognize your character encoding.

Putting all that together, you might end up with something like the following:

```
grep -Po '(*UTF8)(\p{L}\p{M}*|\p{N})+|[\p{P}\p{S}]'

-P      patterns are "perl-compatible"
 -o     output each substring matched

(*UTF8) If the pattern starts with exactly this sequence,
        pcre is put into UTF-8 mode.
\p{...} Select a character in a specified Unicode general category
\P{...} Select a character not in a specified Unicode general category
\p{L}   General category L: letters
\p{N}   General category N: numbers
\p{M}   General category M: combining marks
\p{P}   General category P: punctuation
\p{S}   General category S: symbols
\p{L}\p{M}*       A letter possibly followed by various combining marks
\p{L}\p{M}*|\p{N} ... or a number
```

More information on Unicode general categories and Unicode regular expression matching in general can be found in [Unicode Technical Report 18](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#General_Category_Property) on regular expression matching. But beware that the syntax described in that TR is a *recommendation* and is not exactly implemented by most regex libraries. In particular, `pcre` does *not* support the useful notation `\p{L|N}` (letter or number). Instead, you need to use `[\p{L}\p{N}]`.

Documentation about `pcre` is probably available on your system (`man pcre`); if not, [have a link on me](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt).

If you don't have Gnu `grep` or in the unlikely case that your version was compiled without pcre support, you might be able to use `perl`, `python` or other languages with regex capabilites. However, doing so is surprisingly difficult. After some experimentation, I found the following Perl incantation which seems to work:

```
perl -CIO -lne 'print $& while /(\p{L}\p{M}*|\p{N})+|[\p{P}\p{S}]/g'
```

Here, `-CIO` tells Perl that input and output in UTF-8, and `-nle` is a standard incantation which means "automatically output new**l**ines after a print; loop through every li**n**e of the input, **e**xecuting the following in the loop".

Comment: Wow, I would never come up with this... Thank you! Though I tried the command, and yields error: `>> grep -Po '(*UTF8)(\p{L}\p{M}*|\p{N})+|[\p{P}\p{S}]' sample_corpus.clean.txt 
>> usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoPqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]`

Comment: @user3241376: The you probably don't have Gnu grep, or you have a very old version. What does `grep -V` tell you?

Comment: @user3241376 I suppose you have Mac OS X. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658333/grep-p-no-longer-works-how-can-i-rewrite-my-searches support for `grep -P` was removed last year with NacOSX 10.8. That answer has a perl alternative.

Comment: yep, forgot to mention, I do have a Mac OS X. grep -V outputs `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD` I will check out this answer, thnx!

Comment: @user3241376: Put a Perl incantation in the answer. Hope it works for you. I couldn't figure out how to do it with Python and I gave up before I got too frustrated. If I were you, I'd just install Gnu grep.

Comment: thanks for trying! I first also tried to do it with Python! But then I remembered that I actually have Ubuntu via VirtualBox! So I put your command there and it worked miraculously :) Thank you again !