# GREP regex to extract a session identifier in a json

Tags: regex, json, bash

Let's consider an a.txt file containing the following JSON document :

```
{ "body": { "session_info": { "session_id": "BAzcWu2nHVXrXrx096PMZOaFslgWrjx1", "email": "admin@site.com" }, "status": { "msg": "success" } }
```

I'm writing a bash script for which I need to extract the session_id value.
I started grep'ing with the following regexes, with no success (nothing is returned) :

```
#!/bin/bash
regex="session_id\": \"[A-Z0-9a-z]{32}.*"
echo "REGEX=$regex"
echo "----"
content=$(cat a.txt)
echo $content
echo "----"
[[ $content =~ $regex ]]
sessionid="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
echo ${sessionid}
```

What is wrong with this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easier to do it using `grep -oP`:

```
grep -oP '"session_id": "\K[A-Z0-9a-z]{32}' file.json
BAzcWu2nHVXrXrx096PMZOaFslgWrjx1
```

However for parsing JSON better to use [command line JSON parsing tool: `jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

- `-P` To use PCRE regex
- `\K` reset the matched info in regex

Likely reason why your regex is not working because you are not grouping anything and trying to use: `"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"` which refers to first captured group.

Comment: Upvoted since your solution works. However it'd be even more valuable if you'd explain why question's solution doesn't work, and if you'd explain your solution ;). jq seems a great tool, will try it ! Thank you !

Comment: I added some explanation in question.

Comment: If you on macos, the `-P` argument does not work. You need to use perl directly or install grep with the perl extensions. See the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658333/grep-p-no-longer-works-how-can-i-rewrite-my-searches) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Just to show you how you could do this using `jq`:

```
$ content='{ "body": { "session_info": { "session_id": "BAzcWu2nHVXrXrx096PMZOa FslgWrjx1", "email": "admin@site.com" }, "status": { "msg": "success" } } }'
$ jq '.body.session_info.session_id' <<< "$content"
"BAzcWu2nHVXrXrx096PMZOaFslgWrjx1"
```

Simply filter down through the keys to get to the value you want.

You can use `jq -r` to remove the quotes from the output:

```
$ jq -r '.body.session_info.session_id' <<< "$content"
BAzcWu2nHVXrXrx096PMZOaFslgWrjx1
```

I added the missing `}` from the end of `$content`, as it wasn't valid JSON to begin with. The added advantage of `jq` is that it tells you that.

Answer (score 2):

You will get exactly what you want by using the following regex instead of what you use now.

```
session_id\": \"([A-Z0-9a-z]{32})
```

`${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` is the first parenthesided match, you get nothing because you did use any parenthesis in your original regex.