# git rm --cached everything that is listed in .gitignore

Tags: git, git-rm

I added *.gitignore* to my project after I had everything commited. Now I want to run a command like:

```
git rm --cached *everything_listed_in_gitignore*
```

How can this be achieved? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm always using the following line to remove files listed in my `.gitignore`:

```
grep -vP "^(#|\$)" .gitignore|sed "s/^\///"|xargs rm -f
```

1. This will find lines in `.gitignore` that do not match (`-v` option to grep) the regular expression `^(#|\$)` matching lines that start with `#` (comments) or empty lines.
2. Then `sed` will remove a forward slash `/` at the start of the line.
3. The results are passed to `rm -f` using `xargs`, which you could replace with `git rm --cached`

**Note:**

Your `.gitignore` file can contain entries like `*.tmp` to ignore all `.tmp` files throughout the project. The above command would only remove `*.tmp` files from the root. Only full paths will be handled correctly.

Comment: If `-P` option is missing on your macOS standard `grep`, install one with [`brew install grep --with-default-names`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22704387/798527).

Answer (score 8):

I found another way that works even better in any operating system from https://ardalis.com/how-to-make-git-forget-tracked-files-in-gitignore .

After adding new rules to .gitignore

```
git rm -r --cached .

git add .
```

Basically, it removes everything and adds everything back. When adding, Git will ignore files based on .gitignore

Answer (score 6):

There is a shorter version, the answer is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21477287/5286034).

You can also remove files from the repository based on your .gitignore without deleting them from the local file system:

```
git rm --cached `git ls-files -i -X .gitignore`
```

Or, alternatively, on Windows Powershell:

```
git rm --cached $(git ls-files -i -X .gitignore)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for Windows: 

fatal: ls-files -i must be used with either -o or -c
fatal: No pathspec was given. Which files should I remove?

Comment: perfect in mac OS