# What is perl's equivalent one liner of grep -o

Tags: perl

My question is simple as my title says "What is perl's equivalent one liner of grep -o?". That is print the matched regex only instead of whole line?

```
perl -pe some_option?? 'm/regex/' file
```

Comment: See also: [grep -P no longer works how can I rewrite my searches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658333/grep-p-no-longer-works-how-can-i-rewrite-my-searches/16658690). (Not a Perl-specific question, but the top answer answers this question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do the minimal amount of work, change

```
grep -o -P 'PATTERN' file
```

to

```
perl -nle'print $& if m{PATTERN}' file
```

So from

```
grep -o -P '(?<=foo)bar(?=baz)' file
```

you get:

```
perl -nle'print $& if m{(?<=foo)bar(?=baz)}' file
```

However, it can be simpler to use a capture.

```
perl -nle'print $1 if /foo(bar)baz/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just change the code:

```
perl -ne 'if(/(regex)/) {print "$1\n"}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -nE 'say $& while /regex/g' file
```