# Extract version using grep/regex in bash

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a file that has a line stating

```
version = "12.0.08-SNAPSHOT"
```

The word `version` and quoted strings can occur on multiple lines in that file.

I am looking for a single line bash statement that can output the following string:

```
12.0.08-SNAPSHOT
```

The version can have RELEASE tag too instead of SNAPSHOT.

So to summarize, given

```
version = "12.0.08-SNAPSHOT"
expected output: 12.0.08-SNAPSHOT
```

And given

```
version = "12.0.08-RELEASE"
expected output: 12.0.08-RELEASE
```

Comment: So what you struggling with, can't see any code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following command prints strings enquoted in `version = "..."`:

```
grep -Po '\bversion\s*=\s*"\K.*?(?=")' yourFile
```

`-P` enables perl regexes, which allow us to use features like `\K` and so on.
`-o` only prints matched parts instead of the whole lines.

`\b` ensures that `version` starts at a word boundary and we do not match things like `abcversion`.
`\s` stands for any kind of whitespace.
`\K` lets `grep` forget, that it matched the part before `\K`. The forgotten part will not be printed.
`.*?` matches as few chararacters as possible (the matching part will be printed) ...
`(?=")` ... until we see a `"`, which won't be included in the match either (this is called a lookahead).

Not all `grep` implementations support the `-P` option. Alternatively, you can use `perl`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16658690/6770384):

```
perl -nle 'print $& if m{\bversion\s*=\s*"\K.*?(?=")}' yourFile
```

Comment: `grep -P` works with GNU grep (most versions anyway), but it's not portable. The OP didn't specify what operating system is being used, so it's important to qualify your answer if it is platform-specific. Or even better, make a portable answer.

Comment: very nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a job for `cut`:

```
$ echo 'version = "12.0.08-SNAPSHOT"' | cut -d'"' -f2
12.0.08-SNAPSHOT

$ echo 'version = "12.0.08-RELEASE"' | cut -d'"' -f2
12.0.08-RELEASE
```

Answer (score 2):

Portable solution:

```
$ echo 'version = "12.0.08-RELEASE"' |sed -E 's/.*"(.*)"/\1/g'
12.0.08-RELEASE
```

or even:

```
$ perl -pe 's/.*"(.*)"/\1/g'.
$ awk -F"\"" '{print $2}'
```