# Extract the first character after the first number

Tags: shell

Let's say I have a file like this :

```
14-Hello14657
156:Good morning 487
1478456=Good bye 1 2
```

I would like to extract the first character after the first number of the line (and store it in a variable, one at a time). In this example, it would extract

```
-
:
=
```

I guess that I should probably use regular expressions but I am still learning it and I can't find a way to do this.

Comment: Do you want to store it to the variable one at a time and then process it somehow or all of them at once?

Comment: one at a time, I will precise it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***sed*** approach:

```
s="156:Good morning 487"
var1=$(sed 's/^[0-9]*\([^0-9]\).*/\1/'  <<< $s)
echo $var1
:
```

---

Another approach is ***bash*** variable expansion + ***cut*** command:

```
s="1478456=Good bye 1 2"
echo ${s//[[:digit:]]/} | cut -c1
=
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep (the one installed on most Linux systems) you can use

```
grep -Po '^[0-9]+\K.' yourFile
```

To store the output in a variable, use

```
myVar="$(grep -Po '^[0-9]+\K.' yourFile)"
```

Using your example, the variable `myVar` will contain all three symbols:

```
-
:
=
```

Comment: Is there a equivalent working with every grep version ?

Comment: As far as I know: No. But you can use `perl -nle 'print $& if m{^[0-9]+\K.}'` as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16658690/6770384).