# Why is this grep <regex> not working?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

The following regex with grep doesn't seem to be working:
`grep "(?=\_\(\").*?(?=\"\))" ./testfile.js`

testfile.js is as follows:

```
asoijf oaisdjf _("string 1") fodijsasf _("string 2")
fasdoij _("string 3");
console.log(_("string 4"));
```

My aim is to grab all the strings enclosed in _() function calls, without greps -P flag (the option doesn't exist for me). Expected output would be:

```
string 1
string 2
string 3
string 4
```

Any idea's?

Update: The -P flag was removed from bash in my version of mac (see [grep -P no longer works how can I rewrite my searches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658333/grep-p-no-longer-works-how-can-i-rewrite-my-searches))

Comment: .*? always gives me problems.  Try:  _\("([^"]+)"\) if that works I'll write up a nice answer

Comment: `grep`'s regex syntax is different from and more limited than what you might be used to (Perl syntax). Parentheses are only meta-characters when escaped. It doesn't support lookahead `(?=...)` or non-greediness `.*?`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman It supports all of that with `-P` flag.

Comment: the -P flag is no such option for me

Comment: how about trying provided solutions and let us know then

Comment: Ah, I will try your revised answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following awk and let me know if this helps you.

```
grep -oE '_\([^\)]*' Input_file | cut -c3-
```

Output will be as follows.

```
"string 1"
"string 2"
"string 3"
"string 4"
```

**EDIT:** Since OP doesn't have -P option in it's O.S so providing an awk approach here too.

```
awk '{
  while($0){
    match($0,/_\([^\)]*/);
    st=RSTART;
    le=RLENGTH;
    if(substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-2)){
      print substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-2)
};
  $0=substr($0,st+va+3)
}
}
'   Input_file
```

Comment: That misses string 2

Comment: I thought only 1st should be picked, edited it now, thanks.

Comment: the -P flag doesn't work for me, is this something to do with not having perl installed?

Comment: @Nodeocrat, could you please try my edit solution with awk and let me know if this helps you please.

Comment: @Nodeocrat, I edited my grep solution too now, let me know on same.

Comment: The revised answer ```grep -oE '_\([^\)]*' Input_file | cut -c3-``` works just as desired, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -oP '_\("\K[^"]+' inputfile
string 1
string 2
string 3
string 4
```

Here, `-o` will print only the matched result, not the whole line. 
`\K` will be used for the look behind, Means matches the string left of `\K` but do not print it. `[^"]+` means anything except `"` one or more time.

Or without `-P` option:

```
grep -oE '_\("[^"]+' inputfile|cut -d'"' -f2
string 1
string 2
string 3
string 4
```