# Read word after a specific word on the same line dont have space between them

Tags: bash, shell, unix

How can I extract a word that comes after a specific word in bash ? More precisely, I have a file which has a line which looks like this:

Demo.txt

```
    IN=../files/d
    out=../files/d
    dataload
    name
```

i want to read "d" from above line.

```
sed -n '/\/files\// s~.*/files/\([^.]*\)\..*~\1~p' file
```

this code helping if line having "."

```
IN=../files/d.txt
```

so its printing "d"

here we have "d" without "." as end delimeter. So i want to read till end of line. 
i/p :

Demo.txt

```
IN=../files/d
    out=../files/d
    dataload
    name
```

output looking for:

```
d
d
```

code: in bash

Comment: Deepak: Please mention your full expected output in question.

Comment: @Deepak, so do you mean you have lines without `.` too? As anubhava sir mentioned please add expected output too in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use GNU `grep` with PCRE :

```
grep -oP '/files/\K[^.]+' file
```

The `-P` flag makes `grep` use PCRE, the `-o` makes it display only the matched part rather than the full line, and the `\K` in the regex omits what precedes from the displayed matched part.

Alternatively if you don't have access to GNU grep, the following `perl` command will have the same effect :

```
perl -nle 'print $& if m{/files/\K[^.]+}' file
```

[Sample run](https://ideone.com/fF7iTY).

Comment: @Deepak neither `-o` nor `-P` are POSIX-specified, I guess you must not be using GNU grep. In this case I don't think there are any `grep`-based solutions. I'll leave my answer in case others would use it.

Comment: @Deepak would you happen to have `perl` available? According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16658690/1678362) I could easily rewrite the `grep -P` command into a `perl` one.

Comment: @Deepak I've updated my answer to include a `perl` solution. Note that I haven't got any experience with `perl`, I just followed the linked answer's suggestions. I've added it to my sample run so I can attest it seems to work, but I can't tell if it's really good.

Comment: If this (or anubhava's) answer has solved your problem, please accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

This `sed` variant should work for you:

```
sed -n '/\/files\// s~.*/files/\([^.]*\).*~\1~p' file
```

```
d
d
```

Minor change from earlier `sed` is that it doesn't match `\.` right after first capture group.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't want to think about a single command solution, you can use

```
grep -Eo "/files/." Demo.txt | cut -d/ -f3
```