# Grep Returns Nothing

Tags: regex, grep

I feel like beating my head off my desk so any help is appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'wahegru.com mail is handled by 1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com. wahegru.com mail is handled by 10 ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com. wahegru.com mail is handled by 5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com. wahegru.com mail is handled by 10 ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com. wahegru.com mail is handled by 5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com.' |  grep '(?<=10 )(\.*+\w)*+'
```

Now I know this regex works:

```
(?<=10 )(\.*+\w)*+
```

Because I can paste the text into https://regex101.com/ and the regex and it finds what I need as a full match.

Why doesn't it work for grep though?

Edit, tried this:

```
echo 'wahegru.com mail is handled by 1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com. wahegru.com mail is handled by 10 ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com. wahegru.com mail is handled by 5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com. wahegru.com mail is handled by 10 ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com. wahegru.com mail is handled by 5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com.' |  grep -P '(?<=10 )(\.*+\w)*+'
```

But it gives me this:

```
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
[-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
[--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
[--null] [pattern] [file ...]
```

Tried

```
echo 'wahegru.com mail is handled by 1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com. wahegru.com mail is handled by 10 ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com. wahegru.com mail is handled by 5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com. wahegru.com mail is handled by 10 ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com. wahegru.com mail is handled by 5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com.' | perl -nle'print if m{(?<=10 )(\.*+\w)*+}'
```

But that outputs the wrong stuff:

```
wahegru.com mail is handled by 1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com. wahegru.com mail is handled by 10 ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com. wahegru.com mail is handled by 5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com. wahegru.com mail is handled by 10 ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com. wahegru.com mail is handled by 5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com.
```

Comment: To enable PCRE patterns, pass `-P` option, `grep -P 'pattern'`. To get the matched text, also use `o`: `grep -oP 'pattern'`, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/tB5bUH).

Comment: For some reason, that doesn't work on my mac. See edit for my output.

Comment: [macos - grep -P no longer works how can I rewrite my searches - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658333/grep-p-no-longer-works-how-can-i-rewrite-my-searches)

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work either. Please see additional edit.

Comment: Try `grep -o '10 [^ .]*\(\.[^ .]*\)*' | sed 's/^10 //;s/\.\.*$//'`

Comment: Nice one Wiktor that works as expected. Do you how to output only the first match?

Comment: Add `| head -1`.  If there cannot be consecutive dots, use `grep -o '10 [^ .]*\(\.[^ .][^ .]*\)*' | head -1 | sed 's/^10 //'`, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/NJmrn0).

Comment: Legendary! I'd have been here all week figuring this out. Thank you so much everyone, especially you Wiktor! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
echo 'wahegru.com mail is handled by 1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com. wahegru.com mail is handled by 10 ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com. wahegru.com mail is handled by 5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com. wahegru.com mail is handled by 10 ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com. wahegru.com mail is handled by 5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com.' | \ 
  grep -o '10 [^ .]*\(\.[^ .][^ .]*\)*' | head -1 | sed 's/^10 //'
```

See the [`grep` demo online](https://ideone.com/NJmrn0)

**Details**

- `o` option extracts the matches found in the input string
- `10 [^ .]*\(\.[^ .][^ .]*\)*` matches

  - `10`  -  a literal substring
  - `[^ .]*` - 0+ chars other than space and `.`
  - `\(\.[^ .][^ .]*\)*` - 0 or more repetitions of

    - `\.` - a dot
    - `[^ .][^ .]*` - 1 or more chars other than `.` and space
- `head -1` - gets the first match
- `sed 's/^10 //'` removes the initial `10`  substring.

Comment: You seem to be an expert. Do you know why it gives the wrong answer here?

Comment: echo 'zzzzzz.org.uk mail is handled by 10 d208222.a.ess.uk.barracudanetworks.com. eothenhomes.org.uk mail is handled by 20 d208222.b.ess.uk.barracudanetworks.com.' | sed 's/^10 //;s/\.\.*$//' | head -1

Comment: Impressive. Thanks.