# finding a word from a single character

Tags: linux, bash, unix, gnu

I'm trying to grab a word from a specific character
for example if my sentence was

```
Hello, World!
```

and I wanted to search for e, my output would be

```
Hello,
```

I tried to user grep but had no luck, I also tried this

```
echo "Hello, World!" | grep -o e
```

output

```
e
```

is there any way I could get the output of "Hello,"

Answer (score 2):

Try following :

```
echo "Hello, World" | grep -o "\S*e\S*"
```

And also, if you want to remove all special characters in the string as "," etc, use following :

```
echo "Hello, World" | grep -o "\S*e\S*" | tr -dc '[:alnum:]\n\r'
```

Comment: You can use `\S` instead of `[^[:space:]]` on GNU grep.

Comment: `\S` is generally not supported by `grep` (though some variants have it) but `[^[:space:]]` should work pretty much everywhere, as long as the platform is even vaguely POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell awk to treat each word as a record by setting the Record Separator `RS` to a space:

```
awk -v RS=' ' '/e/' <<<'Hello, World!'
```

On GNU awk, you can set `RS` to a regular expression to match one or more space characters, making things slightly more robust:

```
awk -v RS='\\s+' '/e/' <<<'Hello, World!'
```

The difference here is that multiple consecutive space characters will be treated as a single record separator. Additionally, other space characters (such as tabs) will be included.

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl-compatible regular expressions with GNU `grep`:

```
echo 'Hello, World!' | grep -Po '\w*e\w*'
```

outputs:

```
Hello
```

The command literally means "output a word with an 'e' in it" (`\w*` means zero or more "word" characters).

For MacOS (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16658690/26428)):

```
echo 'Hello, World!' | perl -nle 'print $& while m{\w*e\w*}g'
```