# bash - how to extract all of the same tag in xml

Tags: html, xml, bash

givin this file.xml

```
  <session id = 1111>

    <query text = text1 >
            <response>
                    firstresponse1
            </response>
            <response>
                    secondresponse1
            </response>
    </query>
    <query text = secondtext >
            <response>
                    !!!aresponse2!!!
            </response>
            <response>
                    !!!aresponse3!!!
            </response>
    </query>
    <query text = thirdtext>
            <response>
                    firstreponse3
            </response>
            <response>
                    secondresponese4
            </response>
    </query>
    </session>
```

i want to get both response tags in **secondtext**

output :

!!!aresponse2!!!

!!!aresponse3!!!

.

what is the most efficient way to do that ?

Comment: Bash provides no tools for parsing XML. I expect you'd need to use external tools, probably something that lets you query based on [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath). What have you tried?

Comment: Note that your input file is not a well formed XML. Attributes must be quoted in XML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract XML Value in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333755/extract-xml-value-in-bash-script)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way is to use XML/HTML parsers like **xmllint** or **xmlstarlet**.

**xmllint** solution:

```
xmllint --html --xpath "//query[@text='secondtext']/response/text()" file.xml 2>/dev/null
```

The output:

```
            !!!aresponse2!!!

            !!!aresponse3!!!
```