# Unix XML Parsing inside the tag

Tags: xml, linux, unix

I want to extract value field inside the Value tag like 15846291,15613501. These values can be 0,1,2,3 in a single attribute tag.

```
<Attribute name="Subscriber ID list" basicType="Numeric"><Value value="15846291"><DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="0" value="0" name=""/></Value><Value value="15613501"><DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="1" value="1" name=""/></Value></Attribute>
<Attribute name="Subscriber ID list" basicType="Numeric"><Value value="15846291"><DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="0" value="0" name=""/></Value><Value value="15613501"><DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="1" value="1" name=""/></Value></Attribute>
<Attribute name="Subscriber ID list" basicType="Numeric"><Value value="15552786"><DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="0" value="0" name=""/></Value><Value value="10100543"><DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="1" value="1" name=""/></Value></Attribute>
<Attribute name="Subscriber ID list" basicType="Numeric"><Value value="15552786"><DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="0" value="0" name=""/></Value><Value value="10100543"><DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="1" value="1" name=""/></Value></Attribute>
<Attribute name="Subscriber ID list" basicType="Numeric"><Value value="15167200"><DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="0" value="0" name=""/></Value></Attribute>
<Attribute name="Subscriber ID list" basicType="Numeric"><Value value="15167200"><DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="0" value="0" name=""/></Value></Attribute>
<Attribute name="Subscriber ID list" basicType="Numeric"><Value value="15846291"><DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="0" value="0" name=""/></Value><Value value="15613501"><DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="1" value="1" name=""/></Value></Attribute>
<Attribute name="Subscriber ID list" basicType="Numeric"><Value value="15846291"><DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="0" value="0" name=""/></Value><Value value="15613501"><DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="1" value="1" name=""/></Value></Attribute>
<Attribute name="Subscriber ID list" basicType="Numeric"><Value value="15552786"><DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="0" value="0" name=""/></Value><Value value="10100543"><DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="1" value="1" name=""/></Value></Attribute>
<Attribute name="Subscriber ID list" basicType="Numeric"><Value value="15552786"><DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="0" value="0" name=""/></Value><Value value="10100543"><DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="1" value="1" name=""/></Value></Attribute>
<Attribute name="Subscriber ID list" basicType="Numeric"><Value value="15167200"><DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="0" value="0" name=""/></Value></Attribute>
<Attribute name="Subscriber ID list" basicType="Numeric"><Value value="15167200"><DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="0" value="0" name=""/></Value></Attribute>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extraction of data from a simple XML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222150/extraction-of-data-from-a-simple-xml-file)

Answer (score 1):

You could use xmllint, xmlstarlet or similar cli commands.

For example, using xmllint:

```
xmllint --xpath "//Value/@value"
```

I had to reformat XML to test it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Attributes>
    <Attribute name="Subscriber ID list" basicType="Numeric">
        <Value value="15846291">
            <DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="0" value="0" name=""/>
        </Value>
        <Value value="15613501">
            <DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="1" value="1" name=""/>
        </Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute name="Subscriber ID list" basicType="Numeric">
        <Value value="15846291">
            <DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="0" value="0" name=""/>
        </Value>
        <Value value="15613501">
        <DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="1" value="1" name=""/>
    </Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute name="Subscriber ID list" basicType="Numeric">
        <Value value="15552786">
            <DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="0" value="0" name=""/>
        </Value>
        <Value value="10100543">
            <DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="1" value="1" name=""/>
        </Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute name="Subscriber ID list" basicType="Numeric">
        <Value value="15552786">
            <DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="0" value="0" name=""/>
        </Value>
        <Value value="10100543">
            <DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="1" value="1" name=""/>
        </Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute name="Subscriber ID list" basicType="Numeric">
        <Value value="15167200">
            <DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="0" value="0" name=""/>
        </Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute name="Subscriber ID list" basicType="Numeric">
        <Value value="15167200">
            <DimensionKey  dimensionName="Index" index="0" value="0" name=""/>
        </Value>
    </Attribute>
</Attributes>
```

Good luck!

Comment: xmllint utility is for linux, we are working IBM AIX machines.

Comment: Sorry, take a look at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipclp/index.html or you could try to compile xmllint on AIX: http://xmlsoft.org/downloads.html I think there is precompiled packages. Sorry, I don't have so much experience as sysadm on AIX.