# Use grep to extract the value from the file

Tags: perl, grep

I have the file with the following content:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="/www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:foaf="/xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
    xmlns:jfs="//abc.net/xmlns/prod/xyz/jfs/1.0/">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="//alm.com/abc/users/piku">
    <foaf:mbox rdf:resource="mailto:piku@disney.com"/>
    <foaf:nick>piku</foaf:nick>
    <foaf:name>Pallavi Mishra</foaf:name>
    <jfs:archived rdf:datatype="//www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean"
    >false</jfs:archived>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="//xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Hoe can I extract email id 'piku@disney.com' and name 'Pallavi Mishra' from this file using `perl` or `grep`.

My piece of code is:

```
my $Name = `cat abc.json | perl -l -ne '/<j.0:name>(.*)<\\/j.0:name>/ and print \$1'`;
my $EmailAddress = `cat abc.json | grep mailto | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\\"|:"} {for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if(\$i ~ /@/) print \$i}'`;
```

Comment: Try to use an XML parser like xmllint or xmlstarlet.

Comment: Why is your XML data in a file named `abc.json`? Is that shell code or Perl code? Make up your mind!

Comment: I want to extract these two values from the file abc.json in a perl script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extraction of data from a simple XML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222150/extraction-of-data-from-a-simple-xml-file)

Comment: I think what @200_success means is, why do you have XML data in a file called `abc.json`?

Answer (score 3):

You should use a proper XML parser such as [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML)

This short program demonstrates the idea

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;  # For non-destructive substitution

use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO => \*DATA);

my $desc = $doc->find('/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description')->get_node(1);
my $mbox = $desc->find('foaf:mbox/@rdf:resource')->string_value  =~ s/^mailto://ir;
my $name = $desc->find('foaf:name')->string_value;
print qq{"$name" <$mbox>\n};

__DATA__
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="/www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:foaf="/xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
    xmlns:jfs="//abc.net/xmlns/prod/xyz/jfs/1.0/">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="//alm.com/abc/users/piku">
    <foaf:mbox rdf:resource="mailto:piku@disney.com"/>
    <foaf:nick>piku</foaf:nick>
    <foaf:name>Pallavi Mishra</foaf:name>
    <jfs:archived rdf:datatype="//www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean"
    >false</jfs:archived>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="//xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

**output**

```
"Pallavi Mishra" <piku@disney.com>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* try to parse XML using your own Perl string processing.  That's a nasty unreliable hack.

Perl is a plenty capable language.  You don't need to use shell to help Perl parse XML.

```
use XML::LibXML;
my $foaf = '/xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/';
my $rdf = '/www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#';

my $doc = XML::LibXML->new->load_xml(location => 'foof.xml');
my $Name = $doc->getElementsByTagNameNS($foaf, 'name')->[0]->textContent;
my $EmailAddress = $doc->getElementsByTagNameNS($foaf, 'mbox')->[0]->getAttributeNS($rdf, 'resource');
$EmailAddress =~ s/^mailto://;
```

Comment: I am able to fetch the name using :perl -l -ne '/<foaf:name>(.*)<\\/foaf:name>/ and print \$1'`;

Comment: I have no doubt that you are able to do so. That doesn't make it a _good_ idea. What if, for example, the document contains `&#123;`–escaped characters? XML parsers handle all of those details for you, automatically and correctly. Don't reinvent the wheel poorly.

Comment: XML also has a a variety of valid ways of reformatting semantically identical documents. This makes line/regex based parsing break.

Answer (score 1):

With `xmlstarlet`:

For the name:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v /rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/foaf:name file
```

And for the email address:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/foaf:mbox/@rdf:resource" file
```

You could add to the second one the `sed` statement to remove the mailto part:

```
xmlstarlet ... | sed 's/^mailto://g'
```