# how to extract a value between two tags in unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

```
<trans-unit id="OText.Meetwithcustomer">
            <source>Meet with customer</source>
            <target>\u015eedin\u0163\u0103 cu clientul
</target>
            <note>A step in the sales stage of type qualification in a bid and in a project.</note>
            <note>ID:240645::TYPE:Text/Data</note>
         </trans-unit>
         <trans-unit id="OText.Negotiate">
            <source>Negotiate</source>
            <target>Negociere</target>
            <note>A step in the sales stage of type closed in a standard and in a project.</note>
            <note>ID:240646::TYPE:Text/Data</note>
         </trans-unit>
```

I am passing the trans-unit id to the script and Inside the script, I am trying to fetch the target tag value of that trans-unit id . trans-unit id value can be OText.Meetwithcustomer or OText.Negotiate. If it is OText.Meetwithcustomer , I need to get the value \u015eedin\u0163\u0103 cu clientul and if it is OText.Negotiate,I need to get the Negociere.

How can I do it in a script file. I am looking for an answer which uses sed/awk/grep
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Your sample contradicts your statement `<target>Negociere</target>`

Comment: I am passing the trans-unit id to the script and Inside the script, I am trying to fetch the target tag value of that trans-unit id .  trans-unit id value can be OText.Meetwithcustomer or OText.Negotiate. If it is OText.Meetwithcustomer , I need to get the value \u015eedin\u0163\u0103 cu clientul and if it is OText.Negotiate,I need to get the Negociere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extraction of data from a simple XML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222150/extraction-of-data-from-a-simple-xml-file)

Answer (score 1):

Use a XML aware tool to parse and process the XML. For example, [xsh](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh):

```
open file.xml ;
echo //trans-unit[@id='OText.Meetwithcustomer']/target ;
```

The `//trans-unit[@id='OText.Meetwithcustomer']/target` string is called an **XPath Expression**. There are many tools that support XPath.

Comment: Thanks.Could you please share an answer which is not using any xml parser?

Comment: @arun: The point is you don't need it. It's fragile, unreliable, and harder to maintain. Using an XML-aware tool is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

A non-robust `awk` hack

```
$ awk -v RS="</trans-unit>" '/OText.Meetwithcustomer/' file
| awk -v FS="<target>" 'NF>1{print $2}'


\u015eedin\u0163\u0103 cu clientul
```

Explanation: based on the xml structure extract the record with the search word. Again from this record capture the text next to the target tag.  You can merge the scripts but I think it's better this way.