# Search within xml file(s) in linux

Tags: xml, linux

I have few very large(10GB) xml files, with the following structure. As you can see the file contains series of records. what i would like to do is search record based on one or multiple properties. The problem is that a simple grep would give me the line containing the  property. So for example, grep might give me a line 100, line 300 and so on. But, i require is the capability to extract the relevant record element, not just the lines that met the match. Are there any unix utilities that can help?

```
<records>
 <record seq="1">
  <properties>
   <property name="AssetId">1234</property>
  </properties>
 <message>messsage1</message>
</record>
<record seq="2">
 <properties>
  <property name="VI-ID">4567</property>
 </properties>
 <message>message2</message>
</record>
<records>
```

Comment: There are many options given here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91791/grep-and-sed-equivalent-for-xml-command-line-processing  Also look at xmllint (part of libxml2):  http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html

Comment: What do you want to do with the extracted information?

Comment: If there's one thing this question adds to the prior one, it's having example input text provided -- this makes it easier to provide concrete, visible suggestions that demonstrate usage of the suggested tools.

Comment: save it into a file and convert it a different format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sf.net/) allows you to run XPath from shell scripts; this is a perfect use case.

For instance:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t \
  -m '//record[properties/property[@name="AssetId"][text()="1234"]]' \
  -c .
```

will print the entire record having an AssetId property of 1234.

If you want to do multiple matches within one pass, this is supported too:

```
xmlstarlet sel \
  -t -m '//record[properties/property[@name="AssetId"][text()="1234"]]' \
     -c . -n -n \
  -t -m '//record[properties/property/@name="VI-ID"]' \
     -c . -n -n \
  <input.xml
```

...this version will print either a record with an AssetID of 1234, or any record with a `VI-ID` present with any value, and put two newlines after each record emitted.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way is to use the `-C` option to `grep`.  It will print the specified number of lines around each match.  Yes, it won't stop exactly on a record boundary, but usually just insuring it's included is enough for my needs.

Comment: I get the feeling when the OP says "extract" he means he actually needs usable data and not just line dumps.

Answer (score 0):

In case you only want to use basic unix tools, here's a (stupid) little sed script that can extract out a property that is either on one line, or that spans multiple lines:

```
sed -n '
/<open>[^<]*<\/open>/ {
  p
  b
}

/<open>/,/<\/open>/ {
  p
}' file.xml
```

Sample input:

```
<open>stuff</open>
<otherTag>
otherstuff
</otherTag>
<open>
morestuff
</open>
<otherTag>astlkj</otherTag>
```

Sample output:

```
<open>stuff</open>
<open>
morestuff
</open>
```

Not up for production use: if a tag has multiple attributes, this method quickly becomes difficult, cumbersome, and, if the xml is convoluted enough, impossible. But it ought to do for parsing out information here and there.