# Grep an XML file for certain patterns

Tags: xml, linux, grep

I have a large XML file that has tens of thousands of the same elements:

```
<rootElem>
    <fizz buzz="true">234</fizz>
    <fizz buzz="false">384</fizz>
    <fizz buzz="true"></fizz>
    <fizz buzz="true">39494</fizz>
    <fizz/>
</rootElem>
```

I'd like to run a `grep` that prints out any `<fizz>` elements that do not contain text/body data (the numbers in between the opening & closing tags). In the example above, the `grep` would produce 2 lines for the 3rd and 5th `<fizz>` elements that do not contain the numeric data. The file name is `fizzes_20.xml`. I tried running the following but to no avail:

- `grep fizzes_20.xml "></>"`
- `grep fizzes_20.xml "/>"`

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't you get errors like `grep: ></>: No such file or directory`? File should be the last argument: `grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]`

Comment: Oh wait this is Windows. How do I install grep on Windows 98?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The xmllint command can be used to implement an xpath expression test for empty nodes:

```
$ xmllint --xpath "//fizz[not(text())]" data.xml 
<fizz buzz="true"/><fizz/>
```

## Update

```
$ xmllint --version
xmllint: using libxml version 20901
   compiled with: Threads Tree Output Push Reader Patterns Writer SAXv1 FTP HTTP DTDValid HTML Legacy C14N Catalog XPath XPointer XInclude Iconv ISO8859X Unicode Regexps Automata Expr Schemas Schematron Modules Debug Zlib Lzma
```

Comment: The flag was `--pattern` on my machine. Or, at least, `--xpath` wasn't present. I couldn't get this to work so there may have been a difference between the two.

Comment: @2rs2ts Odd... I have included my version of xmllint.

Comment: Yes, apparently it's a recent addition, and they're (probably) not equivalent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91791/grep-and-sed-equivalent-for-xml-command-line-processing/14492020?noredirect=1#comment25192563_14492020

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to accomplish with such pattern:

```
grep -E '<fizz/>|<fizz.*><' fizzes_20.xml
```

Comment: An XML file sometimes only contains a single line (of many MB). Not so useful for the results then... .

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
egrep '<fizz.*(/>|></fizz>)' fizzes_20.xml
```

The `<fizz` matches the tag opening and title, the `.*` matches any attributes, and the last part in parentheses matches either a self-closing tag or a tag with no contents.  Hope this helps!