# print text inside <project><groupId>..</groupId> and <project><parent><groupId>..</groupId>

Tags: xpath, command-line, xquery, xmlstarlet

I need to list the text inside these two elements in the many `pom.xml` in a directory tree. The files may contain the element at other places too, I am only looking for the content of these two.

Ideally, I am looking for a tool that outputs in the format `<file-name>:<line-no>:<path>:<text>`, e.g.

```
parent/pom.xml:12:/project/groupId:com.acme.project
features/persist/pom.xml:14:/project/parent/groupId:com.acme.project
features/persist/pom.xml:32:/project/groupId:com.acme.project.persist
```

For the following input files:

```
**parent/pom/xml**
<project>
 ...
  <groupId>
  com.acme.project <!--LINE 12 --> 
  </groupId>
...
</project>

**feature/persist/pom.xml**
<project>
  <parent>
    <groupId>
    com.acme.project <!--LINE 14 --> 
    </groupId>
  </parent>
  ...
  <groupId>
  com.acme.project
  </groupId>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>
        a.b.c.d <!-- this is not listed in output -->
        </groupId>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Note that other paths such as `dependencyManagement/dependencies/dependency/groupId` are not included.

Searching here on SO I came across [`xmllint --xpath`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91791/grep-and-sed-equivalent-for-xml-command-line-processing/14492020?noredirect=1#comment22971123_14492020) and [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) but I don't know enough about xpath to figure this out myself.

Comment: Please post example input which should yield this output.

Comment: Output was made up :) But I have made up the corresponding input and added it

Comment: Just realized you need the line number and path to the element. There is no way to get the line number by standard XPath/XQuery, not even in version 3.0. At least [Saxon has some propietary support for this](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.3/extensions.html#linenumber). To the path: there is `fn:path()` for this in XPath/XQuery 3.0, so you will need a more capable and up to date processor. Neither [xmllint] nor [xmlstartlet] support more than XPath 1.0, so you will need another tool.

Comment: I can do without line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath 2.0 compatible query without line numbers, which checks all query paths for matching `<groupID/>` elements and prints their document name, constructs a (not necessarily unique) path and adds the contents of the element.

```
(//project/parent | //project)/groupId/string-join(
  (
    base-uri(),
    string-join(('', .//ancestor-or-self::*/name()), '/'),
    data(.)
  ), ':')
```

You could run it using a [BaseX collection](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Commands#CREATE_DB) for example (like I did for testing), which contains all the XML files you want to query.

1. Run this command to create the collection:
   `CREATE DB xmldocs /path/to/xml-files`
2. Query the database using above XPath

There are different ways to run the query, have a look at the [Standalone Mode manual](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Standalone_Mode).

The query should also run in other XPath 2.0 compatible engines like saxon (which also would support line numbers, see my comment above).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the cygwin build of [xml2](http://www.ofb.net/~egnor/xml2):

```
xml2 <  pom.xml | grep -e "/project/parent/groupId" -e "/project/groupId"
/project/parent/groupId=...
/project/groupId=....
```