# how to read xml file in linux

Tags: linux, sed, csh

I have one xml file as below, I need "en" using some unix command.

```
        <void method="put">
            <string>LANGUAGE</string>
            <string>en</string>
        </void>
```

using below command (got from some link in google),

```
sed -n '/string/{s/.*<string>//;s/<\/string.*//;p;}' Locale.xml
```

I am getting output as

```
LANGUAGE
en
```

so I used

```
sed -n '/string/{s/.*<string>//;s/<\/string.*//;p;}' Locale.xml | tail -1
```

But is there any option in sed by which I can get second value only?

Comment: Using a XML parser might be a better option.

Comment: exact the use case of xpath. if you need to wrap it with a shell script, you could use the tool `xmllint` with `--xpath`. I cannot suggest further before seeing your document structure. Don't try to use awk/sed/grep on a xml, if you want your script to be stable. well you could use those though, for a quick and dirty shot/test.

Comment: XML is not a regular language, which means you cannot match its structures with regular expressions effectively.

Comment: See [Grep and Sed Equivalent for XML Command Line Processing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91791/grep-and-sed-equivalent-for-xml-command-line-processing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `sed`,

```
sed -n '/LANGUAGE/{N; s/.*<string>\(.*\)<\/string>.*/\1/p; }' Locale.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/).

```
$ cat x.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<void method="put">
  <string>LANGUAGE</string>
  <string>en</string>
</void>
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -c '/void/string[2]/text()' x.xml
en
```

Or use [`xmllint`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/xmllint1.html).

```
$ xmllint --xpath '/void/string[2]/text()' x.xml
en
```

[More about XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath).

Answer (score 1):

You can search for `LANGUAGE` and the print next line:

```
awk -F"[<>]" '/LANGUAGE/ {getline;print $3}' Locale.xml 
en
```

Or search for `string` and print the last one:

```
awk -F"[<>]" '/string/ {f=$3} END {print f}' Locale.xml
en
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2):

```
open file.xml ;
echo //void[string="LANGUAGE"]/string[2]
```