# Need to add sub tag in existing xml file using sed or awk command in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a file called abc.xml

### abc.xml

```
<Engine name="private" defaultHost="localhost">
    <Model name="qwerty"/>
    <Host name="localhost" />
    </Engine>
```

I would like to add subtag in Host tag so that my modified abc.xml will look like as below.

```
<Engine name="private" defaultHost="localhost">
<Model name="qwerty"/>
    <Host name="localhost" company="jaguar" >
       <Partner name="xxx" />
       <Partner name="yyy" />
    </Host>
    </Engine>
```

How to achieve above changes using SED or awk command?

Comment: I don't see a question here.  Recommend you read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How to achieve above mentioned change using sed or awk command ?

Comment: Please update the question text to reflect this.  And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: done and thanks for warm welcome :)

Comment: 1) searching for the pattern "<Host" and deleting the whole line and adding new line instead with my changes
2) used command "$temp::2" where temp will have my pattern match string. this will remove "/>" from the end of "<Host ... />" tag. and added manually ">" at the end.

Comment: Did that work ?  If not, what was the result?

Comment: that worked but that's not what I want. Instead of deleting is it possible just to replace "/>" tag of Host element with ">" using sed or awk ?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341361/how-to-read-xml-file-in-linux

Comment: Stock advice: don't try manipulating XML files with line-oriented tools like `sed`. This is bound to end badly. Use XML-aware tools like `xmlstarlet` and `xsltproc` instead.

Answer (score 1):

With `xmlstarlet`, you could do it like this:

```
 xmlstarlet ed -i //Host -t attr -n company -v jaguar \
    -s //Host -t elem -n Partner \
    -i //Host/Partner -t attr -n name -v xxx \
    -s //Host -t elem -n Partner \
    -i //Host/Partner[2] -t attr -n name -v yyy abc.xml
```

Now, this looks a bit more involved, but it is aware of the structure of your file.

Answer (score 0):

cat ins.txt

```
<Host name="localhost" company="jaguar" >
       <Partner name="xxx" />
       <Partner name="yyy" />
```

cat abc.xml

```
<Engine name="private" defaultHost="localhost">
    <Model name="qwerty"/>
    <Host name="localhost" />
    </Engine>
```

cat script.awk

```
BEGIN{RS=""}
ARGV[1]==FILENAME{ins=$0;RS="\n";next}
/<Host/ {print ins;next} 1
```

awk -f script.awk ins.txt abc.xml

```
<Engine name="private" defaultHost="localhost">
    <Model name="qwerty"/>
    <Host name="localhost" company="jaguar" >
       <Partner name="xxx" />
       <Partner name="yyy" />
    </Engine>
```