# Get TagValue of nth occurence of a Tag in XML using sed

Tags: sed

MY xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Attributes>
   <Attribute>123</Attribute>
   <Attribute>959595</Attribute>
   <Attribute>1233</Attribute>
   <Attribute>jiji</Attribute>
</Attributes>
```

I need to get the tag value of second occurence of attribute tag i.e 959595 using sed

i used the command

```
sed -n ':a;$!{N;ba};s#\(<Attribute\)\(.*\)\(</Attribute>\)#\1#2#\2#p' file
```

pattern one second occurrence pattern two value it doesnt work

i dont know whether my approach is correct or not please correct my command

Comment: I would rather use an XML aware command line tool - e.g.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91791/grep-and-sed-equivalent-for-xml-command-line-processing

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to do this is :

```
$ xmllint --xpath '/Attributes/Attribute[2]/text()' file.xml
```

### NOTES

- `xmllint` comes with `libxml2`.
- the '2' is the second searched element

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/<Attributes>/,\#</Attributes># {
  /<Attribute>/ {
     H;g
     s#.*<Attribute>\(.*\)</Attribute>.*#\1#
     t found
     }
   b
:found
   p;q
   }' YourFile
```

- Assuming, like in your sample, there is only 1 Attributes to found, this sed only return the 1st. (if the xml content is only like your sample, the `/<Attributes>/,\#</Attributes>#` selection is not needed)
- Posix version so `--posix` on GNU sed

Comment: If you put an n on you will get the next entry (I think its what the OP wants): sed -n '/<Attributes>/,\#</Attributes># {                                                        /<Attribute>/ {
     H;g;n;
     s#.*<Attribute>\(.*\)</Attribute>.*#\1#
     t found
     }
   b
:found
   p;q
   }' attrib.txt

Comment: not the same. `n` will add the next line to the working buffer without condition (unless last line) and this could be something else than <attribute>, this is why i filter and use holding buffer

Comment: I tested it on my system and it works you already have the /Attribute/ addressing on for the statement, so you probably don't need much of the other things.

Comment: test with `<Attribute>1</Attribute><OtherTag>2</OtherTag><Attribute>3</Attribute>` or simply with `<Attributes><Attribute>1</Attribute></Attributes>` content (all with new line between tags)

Comment: I used the test data from the OP, he wants the second Attribute entry not the first one.

Comment: that is the main problem, is the real data exactly in the same structure. I assume partially this a secure a bit. If really the same, your remarq is OK. This is why, on XML, advice is to use xmlparser if available/possible

Comment: I agree an XML parser is more useful if you need to do anything extensive but for simple value if you know sed its widely available. I just generalized my answer a little bit to select what values to parse, but I wouldn't put much more effort than that.

Answer (score 0):

This sed prints all Attribute entries from the Attributes block, then takes the second entry and removes the tags:

`sed -n '/<Attributes>/,\#</Attributes>#{/<Attribute>/p}' attrib.txt | sed -n '2p' | sed 's#</Attribute>##;s/<Attribute>//'`

```
Output: 
   959595
```

Or another way without pipes is to use sed commands, this goes to the second entry strips the Attribute tag and then quits:

`sed -n '/<Attributes>/,\#</Attributes>#{/<Attribute>/{n;s#.*<Attribute>\(.*\)</Attribute>.*#\1#;p;q};}' attrib.txt`

Or if your number of Attribute entries changes you can make it a bit more intuitive by parsing all values and then using sed to print the attribute placement where you want:

`sed -n '/<Attributes>/,\#</Attributes>#{/<Attribute>/{s#</Attribute>##;s#<Attribute>##;p}}' attrib.txt | sed -n '2p'`

You can change the end where from 2, to whatever Attribute value field you want to display or take multiple values like `sed -n '2p;3p'` or `sed -n '1,2p'`

Answer (score 0):

I also would follow the xmllint xpath way. It however seems like there is two versions available. According to this man page at https://linux.die.net/man/1/xmllint there is no xpath parameter, but it is called "pattern".

Following this documentation, your call then would be

```
$ xmllint --pattern '/Attributes/Attribute[2]/text()' file.xml
```

I recommend checking your local man page to see which one to use.