# How to replace multiple xml lines with bash

Tags: bash, sed

I'm New in bash scripting.

I have xml tabs in file alpha.xml, as

```
<tab>
<enabled>false</enabled>
</tab>
<tabToChange>
<enabled>false</enabled>
</tabToChange >
```

I'm trying to change this to

```
<tab>
<enabled>false</enabled>
</tab>
<tabToChange>
<enabled>true</enabled>
</tabToChange >
```

referencing with https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string

I tried command as

```
sed '/^tabToChange$/ {N; s/\<tabToChange\>n\<enabled\>/yo/g}' alpha.txt
sed '/^\<<tabToChange>\>$/ {N; s/\<<tabToChange>\>\n\<enabled\>/yo/g}' alpha.txt
sed '/^\<\<tabToChange\>\>$/ {N; s/\<\<tabToChange\>\>\n\<\<enabled\>\>/yo/g}' alpha.txt
```

None of them works. Could someone please help me

Comment: show the parent tag which contains those you have posted. I mean there should the "root" tag for valid xml structure

Comment: Use an xml parser not regex.

Comment: Concur with @123, any regex-based approach is likely to be hit-or-miss. Some nice command-line xml tool recommendations here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91791/grep-and-sed-equivalent-for-xml-command-line-processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with the following commands.

```
cat alpha.xml | tr '\n' '\f' | sed -e '0,/<tab>\f<enabled>false<\/enabled>\f<\/tab>\f<tabToChange>\f<enabled>false<\/enabled>\f<\/tabToChange >/s//<tab>\f<enabled>false<\/enabled>\f<\/tab>\f<tabToChange>\f<enabled>true<\/enabled>\f<\/tabToChange >/'  | tr '\f' '\n' > alpha1.xml
cp alpha1.xml alpha.xml
rm alpha1.xml
```

Make that you respect space before any line your want to replace. That is if we have

```
<tab>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
</tab>
<tabToChange>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
</tabToChange >
```

That we want to replace with

```
<tab>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
</tab>
<tabToChange>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
</tabToChange >
```

The commands to use are:

```
cat alpha.xml | tr '\n' '\f' | sed -e '0,/<tab>\f    <enabled>false<\/enabled>\f<\/tab>\f<tabToChange>\f    <enabled>false<\/enabled>\f<\/tabToChange >/s//<tab>\f    <enabled>false<\/enabled>\f<\/tab>\f<tabToChange>\f    <enabled>true<\/enabled>\f<\/tabToChange >/'  | tr '\f' '\n' > alpha1.xml
cp alpha1.xml alpha.xml
rm alpha1.xml
```

Notice that we respect the 4 tabs that come before the `<enabled>false</enabled>`.

Answer (score 2):

To manipulate XML documents use XML parsers/tools.
I would use [***xmlstarlet***](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html) tool.
Supposing that input XML data is enclosed in parent `<root>` tag (you'll have your own tag):

```
<root>
<tab>
<enabled>false</enabled>
</tab>
<tabToChange>
<enabled>false</enabled>
</tabToChange >
</root>
```

The command:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "//tabToChange/enabled" -v true alpha.xml
```

The output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <tab>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </tab>
  <tabToChange>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </tabToChange>
</root>
```

---

`ed` - edit mode

`-u` - to update value

`"//tabToChange/enabled"` - xpath expression to match the needed element

`-v true` - the value to be set

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the recommendation to use an appropriate tool.
But just for the fun of sed:

```
sed  "/tabToChange/{N;s/\(tabToChange>\n<enabled>\)false\(<\/enabled>\)/\1true\2/;}" alpha.txt
```

- be careful with the `<` and `>`
- keep the `\n` in mind you get when appending `N`